# PHP Image cropping working on xampp (dev machine) but crashing page when running on live server

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to crop images when uploaded to become 1:1.

This is alredy working on my dev machine, but when I upload it to my live server, the page crashes saying it can't process the request at the moment.

I've tried to remove the image cropping part and it started working again.

After this, I compared the RAM limits and the dev machine had 512M while the live server had 128M.
I then changed to 512M on the live server.

After that, I tested the cropping again, but with no success. The page keeps crashing.

The folder on the live server has all permissions granted. It's running on Linux (raspbian).
The dev machine is running Xampp on W10.

I replicate the code so there's nothing different in what I'VE done. Maybe it's a difference in the live server configs.

Any tips?

Thanks

CODE:

````
$imgSrc = $fileTmpDestination;
        //getting the image dimensions
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

        //saving the image into memory (for manipulation with GD Library)
        $myImage = imagecreatefrompng($imgSrc);

        // calculating the part of the image to use for thumbnail
        if ($width > $height) {
          $y = 0;
          $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
          $smallestSide = $height;
        } else {
          $x = 0;
          $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
          $smallestSide = $width;
        }
        // copying the part into thumbnail
        $thumbSize = 128;
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

        imagepng($thumb, $fileTmpDestination);```
````

Comment: So, how you want people help you without seing your code ?

Comment: "Any tips?"—Yes: read [ask].

Comment: @Chris what's wrong with the post?

Comment: Compare the configuration of the server with your dev environment using phpinfo().  In particular you want to check the configuration of gd or imagemagick and any associated libraries.  Also, can you check the logs of the server?  Even if the server is returning a 500 error, the actual issue is proabably being logged in the php error log.

Comment: When I commented earlier you hadn't even shown us any code. Now you've added the code, but you haven't given us any error messages. What does "the page keeps crashing" mean? Have you looked at your error logs?

Comment: @gview PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng(). How can this be? I'm using php 7.3. I'm going to research about it but do you have any ideas about this? Thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  GD is not part of the php core as you eventually learned.  Hope you understand, that if your original question had included the error message, you would have gotten a definitive answer from one of the people who responded to you.  Most people won't create an answer, even if it's an educated guess, without the pertinent information that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Had to install the GD library for PHP 7.3.

Used: sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd

Thanks